# Is there a way to "bind" to an Oracle SQL database and get noticed of every update operation in it?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I was wondering... Is there a way to "bind" to an Oracle SQL database and get noticed of every create / update / delete operations in it, by any user?

A bit far-reaching demand, I know... My goal is to investigate how a specific application uses the DB. A good tool for comparing the data (not the schema) between two states of the database would also be a fair solution. A solution without having to dump the DB into a file every time is preferred.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out the DBMS_ALERT package: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_alert.htm#ARPLS351 another option is Logminer: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/logminer.htm#SUTIL019

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What kind of notification you are talking about in the 1st paragraph? You want one that would notify you immediately? Or one that keeps track of CRUD and allows you to retrieve this information after?

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name, thanks, I'll check that. 
@YasirArsanukaev, in the both paragraphs I was talking about the same thing. Your second options sounds like exactly what I need. The immediateness is less important for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would go with

1. [Flashback Data Archive (Oracle Total Recall)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_flashback.htm#BJFFDCEH) available in Enterprise edition, and
2. [Auditing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/auditing.htm) available in any Oracle edition.

The two can be combined to suit your needs.

@a_horse_with_no_name suggested you using Log Miner, and it is a nice solution. But if you are a novice DBA, you can check [Oracle Flashback Transaction Query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_flashback.htm#i1007455) which has a friendlier interface (though it still uses Log Miner underneath to analyze archived redo log files retrieving transaction details).

Some useful info WRT on using built in Oracle Auditing follows.

1. [How to get index last modified time in Oracle?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/73292/119)
2. [Enabling and using Oracle Standard Auditing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/42157/119)
3. [Find who and when changed a specific value in the database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/40420/119) – using [Oracle Fine-Grained Auditing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/auditing.htm#CEGBAFIA), plus some info regarding Log Miner.

Comment: With Total Recall you are able to compare the table contents and structure between at different time points, though it should be enabled for every table separately.